# Is there a way to connect single engine to multiple outputs?

Tags: terraria

I have a few outputs (statue farms etc.) and wonder if there is a way to build only 1 engine and toggle to which outputs it will send it signals (with switches, without cutting wires).

Comment: When you say engine, do you mean timer?

Comment: @PrivatePansy I'm guessing "engine" is the category of things which includes timers and stuff like Crab Engines.

Comment: Engine is a contraption that generates electric impulses. I'm using [Teleporter Hoik Hybrid](http://i.imgur.com/bVCl9SD.png) engine which generates 60 actions/second (maximum possible rate).

Answer (score 3):

That is currently impossible with just wiring, but will be possible with the logic gates soon to be implemented in update 1.3.1.